# IdentityServer3 : client_id, secret, username, password passed in URL vs body parameters

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver3

I am looking at how Identity Server 3 works. In a pluralsight example, I see this for oAuth2
[image]

Does this imply I can add the parameters in the URL?

Whilst I can get the parameters in body to work,
[image]

I cannot get the parameters in the URL to work:
[image]

Is there a setting to switch between body parameters and URL?
Am I doing the URL attempt completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not imply that you can pass the parameters in the URL. For client authentication (passing `client_id` and `client_secret`) the specification mandates that a compliant implementation supports the HTTP Basic authentication scheme as a way for the client to authenticate.

Additionally, a specific implementation may also choose to support client authentication by receiving the `client_id` and `client_secret` in the request body, which is what is being used in the example you mentioned from Pluralsight.

For the resource owner password credentials grant the specification dictates that the requested parameters including `username` and `password` be passed in the request body using the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

As you can see, in neither of the cases it's allowed to pass the information in the URL itself. For security reasons this is not supported and the specification explicitly mentions this in the section related to client authentication (the actual recommended way to perform client authentication is to use the HTTP Basic scheme, but using the request body is acceptable).

> The parameters can only be transmitted in the request-body and MUST NOT be included in the request URI.

---

With:

- `client_id`: ID
- `client_secret`: SECRET

Example of using the HTTP Basic authentication to perform client authentication instead of passing the parameters in the request body:

```
POST /oauth/token HTTP/1.1
Host: jmangelo.auth0.com
Authorization: Basic SUQ6U0VDUkVU
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

code=4/P7q7W91a-oMsCeLvIaQm6bTrgtp7&
redirect_uri=https://oauth2.example.com/code&
grant_type=authorization_code
```

As you'll notice here, the `client_id` and `client_secret` are no longer passed in the request body and instead we have a new `Authorization` header which follows the HTTP Basic authentication rules.

The value `SUQ6U0VDUkVU` in the header represents the identifier and secret encoded in Base64. For demonstration purposes the decoded value is `ID:SECRET`.

Comment: Thanks that does make more sense now. Can I ask where the option is to change between HTTP Basic and request body please?

Comment: Thanks Joao - is there any chance of posting a screenshot of how you use that code in postman please, Im afraid im missing something probably very basic, but I believe if I can see what you see it will become clear. Thank you

Comment: Follow the Basic Auth section instructions available at [Postman - Authentication Helpers](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/helpers). The `client_id` will be the `Username` and the `client_secret` will be the `Password`.